# fixing the function StringVar_WithHistory

Tags: python, class

```
from tkinter import StringVar
class StringVar_WithHistory(StringVar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []

    def set (self,value):
        if StringVar.get(self) != value:
            StringVar.set(self, value)
            self.history.append(value)

    def undo (self):
        StringVar.set(self,history[-1])
        self.history.pop()

from tkinter import OptionMenu
class OptionMenuUndo(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self,parent,title,*option_tuple,**configs):
        self.result = StringVar_WithHistory()
        self.result.set(title)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self,parent,self.result,*option_tuple,**configs)


    def get(self):                
        return self.result.get()


    def undo(self):
        self.result.undo()     


    def simulate_selection(self,option):
        self.result.set(option)
```

I am working on the StringVar_WithHistory class to make it apply to the OptionMenuUndo class. The StringVar_WithHistory has three methods.

**init** (self): initializes the base class; creates a history list for storing the values set is called with.

set (self,value): if the value is different from the current value, set the StringVar to value and remember it in the history list (if it is the same as the current value, do nothing: no new selection).

undo (self): undo the most recently selected option by updating the StringVar and the history list

I tried to run the code and I got the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 omu = OptionMenuUndo(main, 'Choose Option', 'option1','option2','option3')
 self.result.set(title)
 if StringVar.get(self) != value:
 value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'globalgetvar'
```

can someone tell me how to fix myStringVar_WithHistory? thanks

Comment: Do you expect to use this with anything other than an optionmenu? What do you expect when a user types in the entry widget? For example, if the entry has "Hello" and you type " world", what should the history contain. From the underlying tk perspective the variable has changed six times ("Hello ", "Hello w", "Hello wo", etc). Do you want the history to reflect all of those changes? Or do you only want the history to be updated when they press enter or the widget loses focus or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `StringVar.__init__()`

BTW: you have to use `[-2]` or first pop value.

PS. you have to check `self.history` size before you get element because it can be empty.

---

**EDIT 2020.05.22:** In `__init__()` I append first `value` to `history`

```
if 'value' in kwargs:
    self.history.append(kwargs['value'])
```

---

```
from tkinter import StringVar

class StringVar_WithHistory(StringVar):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        StringVar.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.history = []
        if 'value' in kwargs:
            self.history.append(kwargs['value'])

    def set(self, value):
        if StringVar.get(self) != value:
            StringVar.set(self, value)
            self.history.append(value)
        #print('DEBUG:', self.history)

    def undo(self):
        StringVar.set(self, self.history[-2])
        self.history.pop()
        #print('DEBUG:', self.history)

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a = StringVar_WithHistory(value='TEST')
print(a.get()) # TEST
a.set('Hello')
print(a.get()) # Hello
a.set('World')
print(a.get()) # World
a.undo()
print(a.get()) # Hello  
a.undo()
print(a.get()) # TEST
a.undo() # error because self.history is empty

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT 2020.05.22:** The same using `super()`

```
from tkinter import StringVar


class StringVar_WithHistory(StringVar):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.history = []
        if 'value' in kwargs:
            self.history.append(kwargs['value'])

    def set(self, value):
        #print('set:', value)
        if super().get() != value:
            super().set(value)
            self.history.append(value)
        #print('DEBUG:', self.history)

    def undo(self):
        super().set(self.history[-2])
        self.history.pop()
        #print('DEBUG:', self.history)

import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

a = StringVar_WithHistory(value='TEST')
print(a.get()) # TEST
a.set('Hello')
print(a.get()) # Hello
a.set('World')
print(a.get()) # World
a.undo()
print(a.get()) # Hello  
a.undo()
print(a.get()) # TEST
a.undo() # error because self.history is empty

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey, I tried your code and I get the error that NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined

Comment: hey, I fix the init method and I changed it to self.history[-2]), but now I got the new error that "StringVar.set(self,self.history[-2]) IndexError: list index out of range". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: as I wrote - you have to check `self.history` size before you get anything from history. You can't `pop()` from empty history.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call `StringVar.__init__()` in your subclass's `__init__()`, so the var never actually got created.

This is an interesting idea, but I don't think it's going to work as you expect.  Keep in mind that StringVar is NOT a Python object; it's a Tcl object that exists within the Tcl interpreter that Tkinter embeds.  Your overridden `set()` method will ONLY be called if somebody does `var.set()` from Python code.  Any change to the variable that is due to the built-in functionality of Tk widgets will directly affect the Tcl variable; nothing on the Python side is involved.  You may be able to salvage the idea by using StringVar's trace functionality to be informed about changes to the value, rather than trying to override any methods.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said and it does work, but now I get the new error that "StringVar.set(self,self.history[-2]) IndexError: list index out of range" do you have any suggestion for that?